# How to change a directory name?

Tags: macos, terminal, filesystem

My home directory was not where it was supposed to be. I was able to fix the directory location. Then needed to fix the permission of home directory with

```
$ cd /Users/
$ sudo chown -R hook1:staff /Users/hook1
chown: /Users/hook1: no file or directory
$ ls -F
Shared/    chris/      hook1???/
```

Home directory incorrectly appears as `hook1???/` not `hook1/`
Is there a reason for this?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what your issue is... what incorrectly appears?  Can you tell us more specifically what was wrong that you were trying to fix, how you were trying to fix and specifics of what you
 are seeing now that is wrong?

Comment: @Tyson I changed it. When I want to show a command sequence in the question, what do use around it

Comment: It looks like you have non-printable characters in your user name. Will you edit your post with the command and ouput of `id ; id -un`.

Comment: I tried to fix your copy from Terminal (including the parts you've left out), please check and correct if necessary.

Comment: @Chris: please upgrade your OQ with `ls -aBl` (in `/Users`) which is another way to find which characters are at the end of your account name.

Answer (score 1):

If what you posted was literally what the directory name is, then this should work:

```
cd /Users
mv hook1\?\?\? hook1
```

The problem, as fd0 points out, is that you have invisible/unprintable characters in your directory name. Use basic, non-destructive shell commands to isolate the directory name using wildcards, then rename it.  For example, try this:

```
cd /Users
ls -ld h*
```

That should result in exactly one directory being listed. If it does not, continue to add letters before the `*` in order to create a wildcard mask that produces exactly one result:

```
ls -ld ho*     # produces 3 results
ls -ld hoo*    # produces 1 result
```

If you get to a point where you go from more than one result to zero results, then you've stumbled upon another invisible character. Back up one letter, add a question mark then re-add the letter.

```
ls -ld ho*     # produces 3 results
ls -ld hoo*    # produces 0 results
ls -ld ho?o*   # produces 1 result
```

If you still have problems, play around with more `*` and `?` until you have something that produces exactly one result:

```
ls -ld ho*     # produces 3 results
ls -ld hoo*    # produces 0 results
ls -ld ho?o*   # produces 0 results
ls -ld ho*o*   # produces 1 result
```

Once you have that, then use that in your `mv` command:

```
mv ho*o* hook1
```

If none of this works, please post the results of you `ls -ld` experiments.

Comment: `mv hook\?\?\? hook1`    didn't work. Should your second set of commands be   `cd /Users`  `mv hook1* hook1`  I believe you are missing the 1.

Comment: Is my comment format in correct form? Please advise, still new

Comment: Your comment was fine. I originally had `mv h* hook1`, but I didn't know if you have more directories than you showed in your example. Basically, as fd0 points out, you have invisible/unprintable characters in your directory name. I'll update my answer with more details.

Comment: I think this has something to do with.          `The-Glass-Hook:/ chris1$ ls -ld hoo*
drwxr-xr-x+ 15 hook1  staff  510 Jul 15 22:25 hook1???`
`The-Glass-Hook:/ chris1$ cd /Users`
`The-Glass-Hook:Users chris1$ ls -ld hoo*`
`drwxr-xr-x  15 hook1  admin  510 Jul 18 08:20 hook1???`

Comment: `The-Glass-Hook:/ chris1$ ls -F`
`Applications/`           `etc@`
`Incompatible Software/`  `home/`
`Library/`                   `hook1???/`
`Network/`           `installer.failurerequests`
`System/`            `net/`
`User Information@`          `private/`
`Users/`            `sbin/`
`Volumes/`           `tmp@`
`bin/`                    `usr/`
`cores/`             `var@`
`dev/`

Comment: So does `mv hoo* hook1` not work?